# Correct way to handle a transitive .jar dependency in a java library module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.2

Edit:
Note: this problem is fixed in AS3 which now makes jar dependencies transient. Yay.

---

I have an Android Studio (2.2) project using Gradle 1.1 that has a main app and several library modules (both android and pure java libraries).

Some of the java library modules depend on .jar files:

- App

  - libs (directory, all files listed in App dependencies)

    - f1.jar,
    - f2.jar...
  - Module 1 (java library project/module)

    - libs (directory, all files listed in Module 1 dependencies)

      - L1f1.jar,
      - L1f2.jar...

When I run the app in the emulator, it can not find the classes in L1Fn.jar.

I have read elsewhere that I can reference those libs in the main App dependencies using relative paths.

Is there a better way? Can I get Gradle to recognize the need for these files at runtime in the App project?

**As per the request**

Edit:

Main `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app.id"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled true

    jackOptions 
        {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    dexOptions
     {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
     }

    buildTypes {
        release
        {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':theLibraryProject')
}
```

Library build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jar-file-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jar-file-2.jar')
}
```

Comment: Shows us the gradle file

Comment: @EugenMartynov Done.

Comment: Your both gradle files are good from the frist look. I can not say what is wrong. Do you have sample project to reproduce an play?

Answer (score 0):

u should use:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

in your library build file

Comment: Unfortunately I made a mistake in the original question; the second project is NOT an android library, it is just a java library that depends on other jar files, so adding 'android-library' is not an option.